# Create dataframe containing only matching data from 2 dataframes in R

Tags: r

I've seen several posts on similar topics to this but I can't seem to make it work for my needs. I have 2 data frames, df1 and df2. df1 is quite large, df 2 is small.

```
df1 
Chr start end Count
1    0     50   20
1    51    100  40
2    0     50   100
2    51    100  30
2    101   150  7

df2
Chr coord Name
1    25   X
2    75   Y
```

What I would like is to return rows which contain only those that match Chr exactly `(df1$Chr == df2$Chr)` and where `df2$coord` falls in the range of `df1` `start` and `end` `(df2$coord >= df1$start & df2$coord <= df1$end)`

The end result (ideally) should look like this:

```
Chr start end Count coord Name
1    0    50   20     25     X
2    51   100  30     75     Y
```

I know this is probably a basic problem but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you link to questions that seem to be similar?  This isn't a simple merge.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg - though you could merge and cut down if the data isn't too huge - e.g.: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670294/comparing-multiple-columns-in-different-data-sets-to-find-values-within-range-r

Comment: Sure, I was trying to make this work but to no avail. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21173932/combining-dataframe-rows-based-on-a-value-in-a-range

Comment: @thelatemail Yes, that seems to be relevant.  (And what's with these invalid-editors and robo-approvers?)

Comment: I actually looked at that as well. I'm not sure if the merge function will work for me because I don't have a unique gene name in both data frames.

Comment: @PrasannaNanda Note that I rolled back your edit.  Although it was approved, it was invalid.  It made the data hard to input into the interpreter.  In the future, please refrain from such edits, and especially refrain from editing any code in questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This linked question by thelatemail gives the solution: [Comparing multiple columns in different data sets to find values within range R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20670294/comparing-multiple-columns-in-different-data-sets-to-find-values-within-range-r) That question is somewhat muddled and unclear.

This is a duplicate of that question, but this question is clearer and much more readable.

```
x <- merge(df1, df2)
with(x, x[coord >= start & coord <= end,])
##   Chr start end Count coord Name
## 1   1     0  50    20    25    X
## 4   2    51 100    30    75    Y
```